# Meteor Velocity(Jasmine unit): Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, jasmine, velocity, unit-testing

Here are two simple examples. No unnecessary. They do not work. Error is output to the console.

**No asynchronous** tests are working. These - not.

Tests write for meteor application.

About **`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`** I already know, is the **5000**.

```
describe("Jasmine async tests", function(){

        it("First test with timeout", function(done){
            Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
                done();
            }, 300);
        });

        it("Second test, request to google.com", function(done){
            HTTP.get("http://google.com/", {}, function(){
                done();
            });    
        });
});
```

Output to the console:

```
I20141021-21:08:35.178(3)? Async Login Test response to google.com
I20141021-21:08:35.179(3)? Error: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
I20141021-21:08:35.180(3)? at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Comment: Do you use sanjo:jasmine and is this a server unit test?

Comment: @Sanjo, Yes, it's server tests.

sanjo:jasmine@0.4.16.

Answer (score 1):

In unit test mode most of the Meteor API is stubbed out. That means that calling `Meteor.setTimeout` or `HTTP.get` will just execute an empty function and therefore will do nothing. Your callback is never called.

You can find the used stubs here: https://github.com/meteor-velocity/meteor-stubs/blob/master/index.js

Also relevant: https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/issues/55#issuecomment-61026304